# How do I remove HTML from the SAS URL access method?

Tags: url, sas, innertext

What is the most convenient way to remove all the HTML tags when using the SAS URL access method to read web pages?

Comment: I attempted to make your question a bit more clear.

Comment: You failed miserably.  I'm not trying to remove HTML Gobbeltygoodk 
from the SAS URL access method. I'm trying to remove HTML Gobbeltygook from the results of reading a web page with the SAS URL access method.  I am going to have to give you an F+ (failed miserably).

Comment: I was going to have to give you a close vote, so let's call it even? Next time, you should try a little harder.

Comment: I rolled the question back to your original version. You should update it to reflect what you're actually looking for.

Comment: -1: undescriptive title, derogatory language, flames in the comments.  If could add more than one downvote I would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want.  Removes everything between the <> including the <> and leaves just the content (aka innerHTML).

```
Data HTMLData;

filename INDEXIN URL "http://www.zug.com/";

input;

textline = _INFILE_;

/*-- Clear out the HTML text --*/
re1 = prxparse("s/<(.|\n)*?>//");
call prxchange(re1, -1, textline);

run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Warpraptor!!  I really like you elegantly simple solution totally within the confines of a professional programming environment--no need for any amateurish tools like Perl.  With the HTML Gobbelgook removed we are left with beauties like:
Fanaticism consists in redoubling your effort when you have forgotten your aim.
There is no cure for birth and death save to enjoy the interval.
A man is morally free when, in full possession of his living humanity, he judges the world, and judges other men, with uncompromising sincerity.

Comment: Joe, please refrain from smoking that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the methodology is not to remove the HTML from the page, but identify the standard patterns for the data you are trying to capture. This is the perl / regular expressions type methodology.

An example might be some data or table that comes so many characters after the logo image. You could write a script to keep only the data.

If you want to post up some html, maybe we can help decode it.

Comment: I am looking for a purely SAS System solution.  I know SAS Supports regular expressions, and I just want the code so I don't have to do it myself because I don't like reinventing wheels.  The gobbeltygook HTML could be anything doable with Gobbelgook HTML.  I want to read many different kinds of web pages and extract just the content not the Gobbeltygook HTML.